# How to close WPF popup window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing project in WPF and I am facing a problem using a popup window in my project. I use popup control in my window as shown below:-

```
<Popup HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" x:Name="popup" Placement="Center" 
    OpacityMask="#FFC86E6E" Closed="popup_Closed" >
    <Grid Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="0" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.488*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.512*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Frame x:Name="popupframe" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1"  />
        <Button Width="30" Height="30"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                            Margin="0,0,10,-50" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                            ClickMode="Press" Click="Button_Click" 
                            Foreground="{x:Null}">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image/1329666144_button_cancel.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
            </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Now i Create new page in wpf with textbox and button and set this page to popup frame show below:-

```
popupframe.Content=new SessionObjection();
```

Now i want to close popup window with page button. How i do...

Comment: Could you clarify: is it code in `SessionObjection` that should close the popup?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can close the popup by setting the [IsOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.isopen.aspx) property to `false`.

Answer (score 5):

you can try with

```
private void btnClosePopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            popup.IsOpen = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to solve it in the XAML code, here is a working solution (put the Close button inside the popup):

```
    <Button Name="CloseThisPopUp" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="X">
                                        <Button.Triggers>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CloseThisPopUp" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False" />
                                                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                            </EventTrigger>
                                        </Button.Triggers>
                                    </Button>
```

You can also use this code to open a popup, just change the IsOpen property to "True".