# WPF: How to close <Popup> when outside scrollviewer mousewheel action

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I want a solution about close popup control when outside scrollviewer mousewheel changed.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    ....
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="PART_Text"/>
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDown}" StayOpen="False" 
               PlacementTarget{BInding ElementName=PART_Text">
            <Border>...</Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I want to make the pop-up window close Automatically, when a wheel moves, not a mouse click

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close WPF popup window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018641/how-to-close-wpf-popup-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip for the future: you'll have better luck getting questions answered if you make it easy for people. Your code doesn't compile on account of 1) your `StaysOpen` property is misspelled, 2) your `PlacementTarget` setting doesn't have an assignment operator and opening quotation, 3) your `Binding` keyword is mis-capitalized and 4) the setter doesn't have a closing bracket.

To answer your question, all you need to do is add a command handler for the `PreviewMouseWheel` event. Exactly where you intercept the event depends on what behavior you want; if you want it to occur when any control in your application has focus then add it to the MainWindow, otherwise add it to your ScrollViewer:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<ScrollViewer>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseWheel">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewMouseWheelCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Then add a command handler for it back in your view model:

```
    private ICommand _PreviewMouseWheelCommand;
    public ICommand PreviewMouseWheelCommand => this._PreviewMouseWheelCommand ?? (this._PreviewMouseWheelCommand = new RelayCommand(OnPreviewMouseWheel));

    private void OnPreviewMouseWheel()
    {
        this.IsDropDown = false;
    }
```

So long as your `IsDropDown` property supports INPC the popup will disappear whenever a `PreviewMouseWheel` event occurs.